# Partially working depending on item size

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I've included Masonry the jQuery plugin into my design but it's not quite working. The CSS class the documentation provides simply shows:

width: 25%

I changed for my purposes it to:

width: 24%
float: left
margin-right: 5px

which gets it almost right (but unsure if even needed) but the general idea of the plugin is not working as you'll see two large gaps on the left not slotting into place. I cannot tell what other attributes on my 'item' divs may need to change maybe?

I am also using Bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div class="item">
        <div class="product">
          <a class="add-fav tooltipHere" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add to Wishlist"  data-placement="left">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="image"> <a href="product-details.php"><img src="http://quakerrose.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Stapleton-Bench-Furniture-at-Modern-History.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a>
            <div class="promotion"><span class="discount">&pound; 17.00</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="description">
            <h4><a href="product-details.php">Say Cheese Camera Slicer</a></h4>
            <h6><a href="#">By TOMS-TABLES</a></h6>
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/ce/Etsy_logo.png" class="product-src-img product-src-etsy" alt="" title="" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/** Masonry **/

.item { width: 24%; float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
.item.w2 { width: 50%; }

/** end Masonry **/

.item {
display: block;
height: auto;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
margin-bottom: 15px;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you figured out the solution, please don't edit the question but post it as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that Masonry was simply not being triggered on the elements as this:

```
<!-- jQuery Masonry   --> 
<script src="../assets/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js">

    var $container = $('#masonry');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    var msnry = $container.data('masonry');

</script>
```

Where it should have been this:

```
<script src="../assets/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $container = $('#masonry');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    var msnry = $container.data('masonry');
</script>
```

Still not working perfectly but the main thing I asked for was simply to get it initially working which it does now.

Comment: `<script>` tags with the `src` attribute will not run the code inside them. Seems like you had to learn this the hard way.